# Kubernetes API server failing to start: TLS handshake error

Tags: networking, kubernetes

Out of nowhere one of our API servers has started to fail with the following error:

```
http: TLS handshake error from 172.23.88.213:17244: EOF
```

It throws this error for every single node in the cluster, thus failing to start. This started happening this morning with no changes to any infrastructure.

Things I've tried that haven't helped:

- Manually restart the weave docker container on the master node.
- Manually kill and reschedule the api-server.
- Manually restart the Docker daemon.
- Manually restarted the kubelet service.
- Check all SSL certs are valid, which they are.
- Check inodes, thousands free.
- Ping IP addresses of other nodes in cluster, all return ok with 0 packet loss.
- Check journalctl and systemctl logs of kubelet services and the only significant errors I see are related to TLS handshake error.

Cluster specs:

```
Cloud provider: AWS
Kubernetes version: 1.11.6
Kubelet version: 1.11.6
Kops version: 1.11
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to debug this further.

Comment: What happens when you curl the apiserver?

Comment: _no changes to any infrastructure_ is the part I don't believe; in AWS, it will do that if you have a health check pointed at the API server port that does not present a full TLS handshake (so, maybe an NLB or ELB with a TCP health check). The only solution I know of is to switch to an HTTPS health check or move the health check to a different port that doesn't expect -- or log -- the TLS handshake failure

Comment: Most of the time "http: TLS handshake error from x.x.x.x: EOF" means that something is trying to connect with HTTP to HTTPS port, so I would check what service is connecting from mentioned IP:PORT.

Comment: @syscll did you check previous users advices? Did you change TCP to SSL? Here is similar case: https://github.com/dexidp/dex/issues/992